# I would like to sort my files in alphabetical order with each student’s highest score for the tests

Tags: python-3.x

```
def byalphabet():
  if classchoice == '1':
    with open("newFile.txt", "r+")as file:
        file.seek(0)
        scores = file.readlines()
    alphabetical = []
    for i in range (0, len(scores)):
        line = scores[i].rstrip('\n')
        alphabetical.append(line)

    alphabetical = sorted(alphabetical)
    for i in range (0, len(alphabetical)):
        print (alphabetical[i])
    user_scores = {}
    for line in scores:
        name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
        score = int(score)
        if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
            user_scores[name] = score
    for name in sorted(user_scores):
        print(name, '-', user_scores[name])

elif classchoice == '2':
    with open("newFile2.txt", "r+")as file:
        file.seek(0)
        scores = file.readlines()
    alphabetical = []
    for i in range (0, len(scores)):
        line = scores[i].rstrip('\n')
        alphabetical.append(line)

    alphabetical = sorted(alphabetical)
    for i in range (0, len(alphabetical)):
        print (alphabetical[i])
    user_scores = {}
    for line in scores:
        name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
        score = int(score)
        if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
            user_scores[name] = score
    for name in sorted(user_scores):
        print(name, '-', user_scores[name])

else:
    with open("newFile3.txt", "r+")as file:
        file.seek(0)
        scores = file.readlines()
    alphabetical = []
    for i in range (0, len(scores)):
        line = scores[i].rstrip('\n')
        alphabetical.append(line)
    alphabetical = sorted(alphabetical)
    for i in range (0, len(alphabetical)):
        print (alphabetical[i])        
    user_scores = {}
    for line in scores:
        name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
        score = int(score)
        if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
            user_scores[name] = score
    for name in sorted(user_scores):
        print(name, '-', user_scores[name]) `
```

My program seems to output more values then required

```
Aaron - 4
Joeseph - 10
Joeseph - 3
Joeseph - 4
Joeseph - 5
Test1 - 1
Test1 - 10
Test1 - 6
Test2 - 4
Zzron - 1
Aaron - 4
Joeseph - 10
Test1 - 10
Test2 - 4
Zzron - 1
```

Comment: Some general suggestions: (a) Fix the code formatting at the beginning of your post. (b) Remove the redundancy from your code. All branches differ only in the filename. (c) Add your test data.

Answer (score 0):

a more verbose version:

```
import io

file0 = io.StringIO('''Aaron - 4
Joeseph - 10
Joeseph - 3
Joeseph - 4
Joeseph - 5
Test1 - 1
Test1 - 10
Test1 - 6
Test2 - 4
Zzron - 1
Aaron - 4
Joeseph - 10
Test1 - 10
Test2 - 4
Zzron - 1''')

def read_file(fle):
    data = {}
    for line in fle.readlines():
        splt = line.split(' - ')
        if len(splt) == 2:
            name, score = splt[0], int(splt[1])
            if not name in data:
                data[name] = score
                continue
            else:
                if score > data[name]:
                    data[name] = score
                    continue
    return data

def print_data(data):
    for name, score in sorted(data.items()):
        print('{} - {}'.format(name, score))


data = read_file(file0)
print_data(data)
```

output:

```
Aaron - 4
Joeseph - 10
Test1 - 10
Test2 - 4
Zzron - 1
```

Comment: Thank you, i now understand how to do this.

Comment: `read_file` is the first function i defined; `fle` the variable where the function will read from (before python3 `file` was a reserved keyword; i still avoid it and call my file-like variables (the ones i want to `.read()` from) `fle`.